# yadcf settingsDt is undefined in jqueryUI tabs

Tags: yadcf

I have yadcf working on DataTables in a jqueryUI tabbed environment.  When you first load the page, it works correctly.

However, when you click away to another tab, then come back to the previous tab, DataTables blows up and sends the error:

> TypeError:  settingsDt is undefined from line 438 in jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js >(if (settingsDt.oSavedState != undefined && settingsDt.oSavedState.ColReorder >!== undefined) {...)

I have a demo up for you to look at:  www.novobpm.com/yadcf

Click on the "Part Master" tab, it works.  Then click on "Part Alerts."  All is OK.

Now go back  to "Part Master" and it'll blow up.  The error is in the console.  Interestingly, if you now click on "Part Alerts" again, that table is blown up.

```
var oTable;
oTable = $('#part_master').DataTable( {
    ajax: 'tables/parts/table.part_master.php',
    dom: 'B<"clear">frtip', 
    pagingType:'full_numbers',
    order: [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
    processing: true, 
    pageLength : 10,
    searching: true,

    columns: [ 

        { data: 'part_master.part_number' },
        { data: 'part_master.part_description' },
        { data: 'part_master.part_status' },
        { data: 'part_master.add_leadtime_days' },
        { data: 'part_master.add_leadtime_name' },
        { data: 'part_master.max_pph' }
    ],
    select: true,      
    buttons: [
        { extend: "create", editor: editor },
        { extend: "edit",   editor: editor }//,
              ],
    InitComplete: function (settings, json) { }
           } );

    yadcf.init(oTable,[{
    column_number: 0,
    filter_type: "multi_select",
    select_type: 'chosen'        
    }, {
    column_number: 1,
    filter_type: "auto_complete"
    }, {
    column_number: 2
    }, {
    column_number: 3
    }, {
    column_number: 4
    }, {
    column_number: 5,
    filter_type: "range_number_slider"
    },
]);
```

Comment: I'm checking this issue, will update soon (hopefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go grab [0.9.0.beta.7](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/ea86d926de4616fb924e3821643c2da9caa8592e/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) should work now.

Next time you get an error in browser console, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues)

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel, I uploaded the new js and now I'm getting a different error: 


TypeError: oTable.fnSettings(...) is null
 

if (oTable.fnSettings().oFeatures.bStateSave === true && Table.fnSettings().oLo...

You can see it live on the demo I put up for you.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  

Strangely enough, I installed 0.9.0.beta.7 on my localhost version to get it working - then I went back to the demo I published for you and it was also working with 0.9.0.beta.5 still on it (?)  I didn't change anything...I don't know how it started working.

Comment: It beacause your demo is pointing to my local(dropbox) version of yadcf which I fixed thanks to your demo

Comment: oh, right....duuuuhhhh!  :)  I forgot we pointed it at the dropbox.  BTW, my next issues had to do with dropdowns and autocompletes, but your fixes took care of that as well.  Nice work!